# Build tree structure in html using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to build a dynamic tree structure in html. I'm getting result from database in nested json format.

[JSON DATA](https://api.myjson.com/bins/c624h)

I'm not able to read the json data properly. It is in the format

```
[ { keys_1 : { keys_2 : [ array ] } } ]
```

In the tree structre, key_1 are the parents,
key_2 are childern, array items are grand-childern.

How to access this json data so that i can read the parent keys, associated children and then grand children.

I tried this way but couldn't do that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var level_1 = (JSON.stringify((Object.keys(response[i]))[0])).replace(/"/g, "");
    for (var j = 0; j < response[i].length; j++) {
        console.log("yes");
    }
}
```

Even, i'm not able to figure out how to enter the nested json with different key values.
- All keys are different.
- Keys may/may not have children, same with the children also.

How to read the json data in that way so that first it should read one parent children then grandchildren?

Comment: How about scaling that data sample down to a much smaller sampling....just enough to create a [mcve]. Also provide a sample of expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested approach, because you have the following structure:

- array: iterate,
- object: take keys for iterating,
- object: take keys for iterating,
- array: iterate.

```js
var data = [{ 1000: { 110: ["1000110008", "1000110005", "1000110004", "1000110003", "1000110001", "1000110009"], 100: ["1000100001", "1000100002", "1000100019", "1000100018", "1000100017", "1000100015", "1000100014", "1000100013", "1000100003", "1000100004", "1000100006", "1000100007", "1000100008", "1000100009", "1000100011"] } }, { 1020: { 102: ["1020102001"] } }];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        Object.keys(o[k]).forEach(function (l) {
            o[k][l].forEach(function (v) {
                console.log(k, l, v);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```